# Check one checkbox and uncheck previous checkbox

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

So, I have two toggle buttons, the user must be able only to select one of the above two toggle buttons as show in the image below:

[image: 1]

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: use radio buttons? https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/radio/RadioButton/

Comment: Thanks @jbe, but im using ionic version 1

Comment: V1 also have radio button
http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/components/#radio-buttons

Comment: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-use-toggles-like-radio-buttons/21953/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Radio buttons : http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/components/#radio-buttons

But if you want to use toggle button and achieve this thing, you can use $watch : [Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

Ionic code:

```
 <label class="toggle">Bride only
     <input type="checkbox" ng-model="B">
     <div class="track">
         <div class="handle"></div>
     </div>
 </label>

<br>

 <label class="toggle">Bride & Bridesmaids
     <input type="checkbox" ng-model="B&B">
     <div class="track">
         <div class="handle"></div>
     </div>
 </label>
```

Angular code:

```
$scope.B=false; // for Bride only
$scope.B&b= false //for Bride and Bridesmaids

$scope.$watch('B',function(){

  if($scope.B==true){
    $scope.B&B=false;
    console.log($scope.B&B);
  }

}); 

$scope.$watch('B&B',function(){

  if($scope.B&B==true){
    $scope.B=false;
    console.log($scope.B);
  }

});
```

Hope this helps.